# how to detect Linux shutdown/reboot

Tags: c, linux, shutdown

I'm trying to detect shut down or reboot from Linux in my c program.
I found that program can use signal(SIGTERM, handler) (SIGKILL, handler).
But these two will trigger if user kill the process with command, too.

At some solutions, they said can use runlevel but it won't work.
Don't know if the process is kill before the system init the runlevel.
I even try to put script in rcx.d, but it still won't work.

Does anyone has some advise?
I need to run on many kinds of Linux system.

Thanks.

[Update]
I use R solution, but I still don't see my data were clear at reboot or shutdown.
Is it my function is wrong??

```
int start() {
    if (initIni() == EXIT_FAILURE)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, '\0', sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = &signal_callback_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL);
....
}

void signal_callback_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context) {
    if (signum == SIGTERM && (long)siginfo->si_pid == 1) {
        clearData();
    }
    exit(signum);
}
```

[Update]
Finally, I use David Schwartz runlevel(8) [example](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/sysvinit/src/runlevel.c) to solve my problem.
It won't be useful if you use linux command runlevel.
Thanks for the great solution.

Comment: What do you want to do with this shutdown/reboot signal? Restart the process, in example?

Comment: there is difference between hardware and software signals.

Comment: note SIGKILL cannot be caught!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I detect shutdown/reboot from linux app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269825/how-do-i-detect-shutdown-reboot-from-linux-app)

Comment: I would use the signal to clear some data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect pending system shutdown on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832376/how-to-detect-pending-system-shutdown-on-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catch SIGTERM. In the handler, read the `/var/run/utmp` file to get the runlevel. See the [source code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/sysvinit/src/runlevel.c) of the `runlevel(8)` command for reference.

Answer (score 8):

Your assumptions are mistaken. There is no way to catch `SIGKILL`; it terminates the process with no chance to respond to it.

With that said, I may have a solution: you can catch `SIGTERM`, and if you install the signal handler with `sigaction` and the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, you should be able to determine which process sent you the `SIGTERM` signal. If it came from `init` (pid 1), it's a shutdown. This is mildly hackish but might work for your purposes.

Comment: hello, I try to use you solution but it still won't be trigger at shutdown. Please see my update above. Thanks.