# reboot parent process in c linux

Tags: c, linux

I have a parent process and set of child process associated with it.

If I run `system("reboot")` in parent process,

1. What signal will be sent to the child process?
2. Are we able to handle those signals?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to detect Linux shutdown/reboot\[solved\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009705/how-to-detect-linux-shutdown-rebootsolved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a system reboot init sends SIGTERM to all the child process and waits for it to terminate.
It again sends SIGTERM after some time if the child did not terminate and finally sends a SIGKILL which cannot be blocked to kill the child.

Answer (score 1):

1. Possibly SIGTERM or SIGKILL, which are sent by `init` as the system is rebooted.
2. Sort of, but not really. You can trap SIGTERM, but SIGKILL is always fatal, and the system is rebooting anyway. Your process is inevitably going to die when that happens.